# CouchDB: Correlation between update seq and document _id

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to use _changes API while dynamically determining the update sequence to start from (`_changes?feed=longpoll&since=SEQ`). I want to get `SEQ` number based on the `doc._id` for let's say, all the docs that have field `doc.doctype === "data"` (I'll be using filters for that). Is this possible? I understand that my problem can be solved using different design documents, but I want to do this using only one design doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no correlation between a document's id (or rev) and the database's seq number. The seq number is only relevant to a database on a single machine (think replication).

So, the only place I know of to get a useful seq number is the 'update_seq' returned by GET'ing a database resource's URL:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5984/scratch
{"db_name":"scratch","doc_count":2,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":3,
"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":28761,
"instance_start_time":"1310481969310904","disk_format_version":5,
"committed_update_seq":3}
```